# Best opencv version to use for face and eye detection

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm a newbie and i want to know what version of opencv should i use for face and eye detection .
i have found that since opencv 3.0.0 it offers a new api in c++ so there is more speed especially in multiple cores and more non faces can be detected but i want to use it also in detection of eye direction
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use the new one,i find it has trained a lot of classifers,whice are in `opencv/data/haarcascades/`,so you can use it directly or train a new one by yourself

Answer (score 1):

If you are a newbie I would recommend using `OpenCV 2.4.x` as there are quite a lot of resources on the internet using that version. `OpenCV 3` is new and you may not be able to find online help for it as easily as you can get for `2.4.x`